# separate values using "," as my delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set with multiple values for a single column I am trying to separate them using "," as my delimiter.

my data looks like this:

```
A:            B:           C:
1             A,B,C,D      Square
2             E,F          Triangle
3             G,H,I        Circle
```

I am trying to process it in such a way as to get these results:

```
A:           B:           C:
1            A            Square
1            B            Square
1            C            Square
1            D            Square
2            E            Triangle 
2            E            Triangle
3            G            Circle
3            G            Circle
3            I            Circle
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First split the column values using `Series.str.split` then explode the column:

```py
>>> df.assign(B=df['B'].str.split(',')).explode('B')

   A  B         C
0  1  A    Square
0  1  B    Square
0  1  C    Square
0  1  D    Square
1  2  E  Triangle
1  2  F  Triangle
2  3  G    Circle
2  3  H    Circle
2  3  I    Circle
```